# Fixing bad dates in multi record table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where it has records of participation data with start and end dates. Sometimes there are bad dates such as below:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+
|   ID   | Start_Date | End_Date  |
+--------+------------+-----------+
| ABC123 | 1/2/2018   | 6/1/2020  |
| ABC123 | 5/1/2027   | 12/2/2017 |
| ABC123 | 1/1/2015   | 4/5/2017  |
+--------+------------+-----------+
```

Is there a script that would replace the bad start date with the end date of previous record to make it look like the table below

```
+--------+------------+-----------+
|   ID   | Start_Date | End_Date  |
+--------+------------+-----------+
| ABC123 | 1/2/2018   | 6/1/2020  |
| ABC123 | 4/5/2017   | 12/2/2017 |
| ABC123 | 1/1/2015   | 4/5/2017  |
+--------+------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arc89, I think it will be easier to write your own function. Take a look at this:

```
def get_correct_dates(row):
    """ this function checks if start date is past the end date, if yes it takes the previous date"""
    if pd.isna(row["prev_End_Date"]):
        return row["Start_Date"]

    if row["Start_Date"] > row["End_Date"]:
        return row["prev_End_Date"]
    else:
        return row["End_Date"]


df["prev_End_Date"] = df.groupby("ID")["End_Date"].shift(-1)
df["Start_Date"] = df.apply(lambda row: get_correct_dates(row), axis=1)
df.drop("prev_End_Date", axis=1, inplace=True)
```